# CSS Class Property not overwriting ASP

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm having an issue where I can't get the summary of a redgex to format how I want.

I have put the css classes within the same aspx file as the redgex summary and marked them as important. However still when I run it, it's not being used.

## Update

Within Chrome's inspect element it's saying that the redgex summary style is red. The HedderText comes up red, it seems to be the list items that aren't following suit but I don't know why they're not overriding the default.

Any ideas?

Chrome showing it's not being used but don't know why:

[image]

CSS:

```
        .valError {
        color:red !important;
    }

    .validation_summary {
        color:red !important;
    }
```

ASP Redgex Summary:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" 
runat="server" 
ShowMessageBox="false" 
ShowSummary="true" 
ValidationGroup="v1" 
ForeColor="Red" 
DisplayMode="BulletList" 
CssClass="valError" 
HeaderText="<span>The below requires attention.</span>"/>
```

Comment: How looks the generated html source code from your aspx component?

Comment: It's saying that the summary style is red, according to Chrome's inspect element. The HedderText comes up red, it seems to be the list items that aren't following suit but I don't know why they're not overriding the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any styling applied, **ValidationSummary** renders as a boring list with error messages.

However, it’s easy to pretty it up with some **CSS** since it’s nothing more than a div with an unordered list inside.So you have to define in your example and the class `.valError ul`

Let's see it with an example:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" 
    DisplayMode="BulletList" 
    CssClass="valError" />
```

Next, put it in a box with a red border

```
.valError{
 border: 2px solid red;
 color: red;
 margin: 5px 0px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

Let's say we want padding and margins on the error list and move it to the right

```
.valError ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: 80px;
 list-style: square;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, certainly makes it look more impressive, however the list items are still not coloured and have no idea why. Added color:red to both ul and li classes but still it's not overriding the default.

Comment: can you give me the html from google console. right click and copy html all the element to check this out?

Comment: There's a lot of it, being the only issue - where shall I put it?

Comment: create a jsfiddle and send me the link plz

Comment: Apologies for the delay - can't do that, just more annoyed at why the CSS class is not taking priority. There is already CSS set for global lists.